# What is the generalization of "real vector space can only have a complex structure if it is even-dimensional" in infinite dimensions?

Tags: vector-spaces

As per the question in the title, the proof that I've seen in finite-dimensions uses determinants and I'm not sure what the statement would even be in infinite dimensions. Do all infinite-dimensional spaces admit complex structures $J$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3518285/269764